# daemon behaviour multiprocessing multithreading

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread

def main():

    thread1 = myclass(varA)   #subclassed threading.Thread
    thread1.daemon = False
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = Thread(target=myfunc)
    thread2.daemon = False
    thread2.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    SUBPROCESS = Process(target=main)
    SUBPROCESS.daemon = False
    SUBPROCESS.start()
```

Why does the script die unless I add the while True: sleep in main()?  (both thread1 and thread2 have functions that run forever)
Shouldn't the daemon = False, keep them alive (the subprocess AND the subthreads in that subprocess) even when the parent process has ended?

EDIT1 (Working code)(have a look at the comments on Method A or method B, comment block one of the sections when running):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread
import time


varA = "XYZ"

class myclass(Thread):

    def __init__(self, varA):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.varA = varA

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("myClass prints %s" %self.varA)


def myfunc():
    while True:
        print("myfunc prints")



def main():

    thread1 = myclass(varA)   #subclassed threading.Thread
    thread1.daemon = False
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = Thread(target=myfunc)
    thread2.daemon = False
    thread2.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #METHOD A: Running as subprocess = subthreads in that subprocess will die
    SUBPROCESS = Process(target=main)
    SUBPROCESS.daemon = False
    SUBPROCESS.start()


    #METHOD B: Running as main process = subthreads in that subprocess wont die as desired
    thread1 = myclass(varA)   #subclassed threading.Thread
    thread1.daemon = False
    thread1.start()

    thread2 = Thread(target=myfunc)
    thread2.daemon = False
    thread2.start()
```

Comment: Post code that we can actually run, that actually reproduces the error when run. Also, don't tag your question with both python-3.x and python-2.7; if your question is version-specific, pick the tag for the version you're actually using. If your question is not version-specific, don't use a version tag.

Comment: Well the code is working fine WITH the while True loop, I'm wondering why it dies after a while IF i remove the while True loop in main() (subprocess dies when parent process terminates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [Python issue 18966](https://bugs.python.org/issue18966); multiprocessing processes didn't `join` non-daemon threads before shutdown. The behavior has been changed in Python 3.7.0 so processes now `join` their non-daemon threads.

Comment: Wow thanks I'll try this in python 3.7. Apart from stackoverflow, is there somewhere you recommend to post these kind of newbie-ish questions? I honestly find stackoverflow to be hard for newbies trying to self-learn the language.

Comment: @duarte: I wish I knew a place to recommend.